# Delete keeps going to the Show page on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm trying to create a blog in rails, and I'm having a little trouble. I keep getting the page for my show method each time I try to use my destroy method to test deleting an article from my blog. This is the destroy method:

```
def destroy
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @article.destroy
 flash[:notice] = "Article has been deleted."
 redirect_to articles_path
end
```

And this is the index file for the home page:

```
<h1>Listing all articles</h1>
<p>
   <%= link_to "Create new artilce", new_article_path %>
</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Titile</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete,  data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
   </tr>
     <% end %>
  </table>
```

If someone could please tell me where the faulty code is, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your code looks fine. make sure you have JS running in your app.

Comment: How would I know if my javascript is running in my application?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a javascript / jquery issue.

Rails [sets the "method" with a form](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), using JQuery to define it explicitly:

> This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete, :patch, and :put. **Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET**

Thus, if you have Javascript / JQuery disabled, your `link_to` will simply be `GET`, which sends the request to the `show` action.

--

You need to make sure you have the following:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: It seems that I have that. Is there possibly another reason that it is not working?